# Why is there no output from my function in Rstudio?

Tags: r, matrix, return

I'm a beginner on Rstudio so I may ask some stupid questions. When I type this function: `my.bivariate.dice.matrix(Nreps=2, Nsample = 5)`
 I get

```
##      [,1] [,2]
## [1,]    5   10
## [2,]    2    6
## [3,]    5    5
## [4,]    5    6
## [5,]    7    5
```

from my console.

But when I type this funtion:

```
my.bivariate.dice <- function(die1=1:6, die2=1:6, prob1=NULL,prob2=NULL,Nsample=20) {
  roll1 <- sample(die1, prob=prob1, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
  roll2 <- sample(die2, prob=prob2, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
  my.result <- roll1 + roll2
  return(my.result)
}
```

I get a copy of the exact same function in the console section.

```
> my.bivariate.dice <- function(die1=1:6, die2=1:6, prob1=NULL,prob2=NULL,Nsample=20) {
+   roll1 <- sample(die1, prob=prob1, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
+   roll2 <- sample(die2, prob=prob2, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
+   my.result <- roll1 + roll2
+   return(my.result)
+ }
```

No output is shown.

---

My first question is, how to get the output from the second function? What step did I do wrong or miss? Or is it supposed to be like that in the console section?

Whenever I type `view(my.result), sample(my.result), plot(my result)`, I get something like below:

```
Error in View: object 'my.result' not found
```

But if I switch it into `view (my.bivariate.dice()), sample (my.bivariate.dice())` and so on, I get what I want respectively as the diagram or graph.

So my second question is that why `my.bivariate.dice()` can be checked, while `my.result` or any random character/number inserted in the function cannot be found.

Thanks a lot for whoever answers my questions.

Comment: running test <- my.bivariate.dice()` works for me, can you share the code that is producing the output?

Comment: Is it just a matter of calling the function and assigning the result of the function to a variable? If you want those `View()` statements to work, for example, first try `my.result <- my.bivariate.dice()` and _then_ trying the `View()` statements.

Comment: (I removed your [tag:rstudio] tag. From its description if you mouse-over the tag: *"**Do not** use this tag for general R programming problems, just use the R tag."*)

Comment: On the console, you should never be able to see (without more effort) the value of `my.result`, for a couple of reasons: (1) it is *inside* of the function, you are *outside* the function; (2) that variable only exists while the function is actively executing, but while you are on the console and at the normal `> ` prompt, the function is not running *so the variable does not exist*.

Comment: Hi r2evans, so what should I do to get the value of my.result?

Comment: Read about the concept of **scope** in programming. The variable `my.result` only exists within the _scope_ of  the function and doesn't exist outside in the global environment. When you `return` it, the contents of `my.result` are passed out of the function and printed, assigned to another variable (as you do here), or passed to another function

Answer (score 1):

Objects must be defined to be used.

If I type `x` in the R console, (in a fresh R session), I will get an error:

```
> x
`Error: object 'x' not found`
```

Because R doesn't know what `x` is. But if I define `x` first (assigning a value to it with `<-` or `=`), then I can see its value just fine:

First define it (notice no result is printed, only the assignment command that I run):

```
> x <- 5
```

Now we can see `x`, or use it:

```
> x
[1] 5

> sqrt(x)
[1] 2.236068
```

---

Just the same, in my fresh R session, the function `my.bivariate.dice` doesn't exist. If I try to call it, I will get an error:

```
> my.bivariate.dice(Nsample = 5)
Error in my.bivariate.dice(Nsample = 5) : 
  could not find function "my.bivariate.dice"
```

But if I define it first, using `<-`, then I can use it:

```
> my.bivariate.dice <- function(die1=1:6, die2=1:6, prob1=NULL,prob2=NULL,Nsample=20) {
+   roll1 <- sample(die1, prob=prob1, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
+   roll2 <- sample(die2, prob=prob2, replace = TRUE, size = Nsample)
+   my.result <- roll1 + roll2
+   return(my.result)
+ }
```

(The `+` at the beginning of the line is the R console's way of telling you that the line is continued from the one above. You shouldn't include the `+`s in your code, the are added by the console, just like the `>` at the beginning of the first line)

Just like nothing printed when I assigned `x <- 5` above, nothing prints when I assign `my.bivariate.dice <- ...` here. But I can call the function now:

```
> my.bivariate.dice(Nsample = 5)
[1] 6 3 6 9 8
```

If I want to use that result later, I need to assign it to an object, using `<-` or `=`:

```
> my.result = my.bivariate.dice(Nsample = 5)
```

It doesn't matter what names are used *inside* the function, I can call the result `result` or `my.result` or `x` or `jerry` or any name I want. And now that I've assigned the values I want to `my.result`, I can use `my.result` with `View()` (notice the capital `V`) or any other function.

Note that this is a *very good thing* that the function didn't pick a name for me. I don't want to keep track of what names are used *inside* functions. Above, when I ran the command `sqrt(x)`, if I had wanted to save that result, I would want to pick my own name, `my.sqrt <- sqrt(x)`---and that's how R works. I don't want to look inside `sqrt()` or at the documentation to figure out what the result is called, I pick whatever name I want.

Comment: Thank you very much, Gregor. You have made it very clear for me.

Comment: @安西节度使 Glad it helped. If your question is resolved, please "accept" my answer by clicking the checkmark in the margin to the left of the question. This will indicate you are not waiting for more answers (and give us both a little bit of reputation points).